# Why do I have so many duplicated processes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm stressing my kubernetes API and I found out that every request is creating a process inside the Worker Node.

**Deployment YAML**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${KUBE_APP_NAME}-deployment
  namespace: ${KUBE_NAMESPACE}
  labels:
    app_version: ${KUBE_APP_VERSION}
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app_name: ${KUBE_APP_NAME}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app_name: ${KUBE_APP_NAME}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ${KUBE_APP_NAME}
          image: XXX:${KUBE_APP_VERSION}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: MONGODB_URI
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb
                  key: uri
            - name: JWT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt
                  key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

**Apache Bench used** ab -p payload.json -T application/json -c 10 -n 2000

Why is this?

[image: htop screenshoot]

Comment: You mean each request is creating a process inside the deployment pods?

Comment: Not inside the pod but inside the Kubernetes Worker Node

Comment: Can you tell me how was the cluster deployed, what is the CNI and what versions are you running?

Comment: Kubernetes 1.18 (in house server) with Calico

Comment: How was the cluster deployed?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific ? Long story short: I followed the documentation.

Comment: By "creating a process inside the Worker Node" do you mean it is creating new containers, or just new processes inside the same container?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your questions if this is normal that the requests are being kept open.
We don't know what exactly is your `payload` and how big it is. We also don't know if the image that you are using is handling those correctly.

You should use verbose=2 `ab -v2 <host>` and check what it taking so long.

You are using Apache Bench with `-c 10 -n 2000` options which means there will be:

- -c `10` concurrent connections at a time,
- -n `2000` request total

You could use -k to enable HTTP KeepAlive

> `-k`
>
> Enable the HTTP KeepAlive feature,  *i.e.*, perform multiple requests within one HTTP session. Default is no KeepAlive.

It would be easier if you provided the output of using the `ab`.

As for the Kubernetes part.

We can read a definition of a `pod` available at [Viewing Pods and Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/):

> A Pod is a Kubernetes abstraction that represents a group of one or more application containers (such as Docker or rkt), and some shared resources for those containers
>   ...
>   The containers in a Pod share an IP Address and port space, are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context on the same Node.